# Get struct's size passed as void to function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, sybase

I'm changing some codes in a database library. The way it works I send a void pointer, to get the size of it I call a query and using the query I calculate the size of the structure. Now the problem is I receive the struct as params but the function fails before/in the middle of the first fetch. After that I need to clear the structure, but I dont even have the size.
I know the best way is send the size of the structure as a param, but I have thousands and thousands programs already compiled, the library is from 1996, so I need to find a way to calculate the structure size even if the type is void.

One idea I had was to calculate the position of the next element that is not in the structure

```
0x000010              0x000042
[int|char[30]|int|int][int]
```

So the size is 32, because the 0x00042-0x000010 is 32.

Is there a way to know when I got out of the structure.

the prototype of the function is

```
int getData(char* fields, void* myStruct)
```

I need to find out the structure size.

Sorry if I missed some information, the code is HUGE and unfortunately I cannot post it here.

Comment: are you casting myStruct to some struct type?  If so can you just use sizeof that struct?

Comment: what is `0x000010 0x000042 [int|char[30]|int|int][int]` ? BTW "0x00042 - 0x000010" is *0x*32.

Comment: Do you know anything about the struct layout? Is is variable sized, depending on the first int field? BTW: the size 0x32 (50 decimal) is not very probable, since the ints need to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary (assuming 4 byte ints, etc)

Comment: the address are just to illustrate the problem, they are not real

Answer (score 5):

No, in general there's no way, given a `void *`, to figure out what you're after. The only thing you can do is compare it against `NULL`,  which of course doesn't help here.

Note that there's nothing in the `void *` that even says it points at a `struct`, it could just as well be pointing into the middle of an array.

If you have some global means of recording the pointers before they're passed to `getData()`, you might be able to implement a look-up function that simply compares the pointer value against those previously recorded, but that's just using the pointer value as a key.

Comment: Yup, main drawback of `void*` is that it literally means *no type information at all*...